# Children's fantasy book with black and gold "urchins" (hedgehogs)

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, animals

I remember a fantasy book in which one of the elements was magic hedgehogs, only they called them “urchins.”  There were ones with gold spines and ones with black spines, and the black ones' spines were poisonous.
Unfortunately, I can't remember anything else about the book, or if I can I've forgotten it was the same book.  I’m vague about the date; it could be any time between 1990s and now — and that's assuming it wasn't second-hand at the time, though I rather think it wasn't.  Does anybody here happen to recognise these hedgehogs?

Edited to add: There might possibly have been a unicorn?  But I may be mixing it up with a different book entirely there.

Comment: Interestingly, ["sea urchins" got named that because they looked like hedgehogs, which were, at the time, called "urchins"](https://kathrynannasite.wordpress.com/2019/09/15/ceramic-sea-urchins/)

Comment: I got hopeful when I saw some description of *Barkbelly*, but it seems the "urchins" he tends are regular, if large, hedgehogs.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be *Barkbelly*, too (I'd read it some time ago, but don't remember much about it), but after looking it up I realised it wasn't, unless there's more to the hedgehogs than the reviews etc. I looked at mentioned.